# How to use foreach on fetch response in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am getting data through `fetch` on its response i want to use foreach loop but it is not working

```
 fetch(url, options).then((response) => {
 
            response.json().forEach((work_order) => {
})
})
```

giving this error

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
```

console result

```
Response {type: "cors", url: "http://siloc.xyz/api/gangBoss/workOrders/view/17", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "cors"
url: "http://siloc.xyz/api/gangBoss/workOrders/view/17"
__proto__: Response
```

Comment: `response.json()` returns a Promise - odd that it's returning `undefined` though

Comment: You should be getting `undefined`. I would expect the error to be `TypeError: res.json().forEach is not a function`?

Comment: I just ran your code on the website http://siloc.xyz/ and I got the error `TypeError: res.json().forEach is not a function`. Please may you make sure the code in the question is what you used?

Comment: Ok. If that is the error (which is different from the one you said before), then try putting the `forEach` inside a `then`? `response.json().then(data => data.forEach(...))`

Comment: I am getting the error which i highlighted in question 

with same code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `fetch` sends the request itself, the returned promise does not resolve when the server response is fully received.

The response object represents the stream of data. Because of that - `res.json()` returns another [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json).

Try this:

```js
fetch(url, options).then(response => response.json()).then(jsonResponse => {
  if (Array.isArray(jsonResponse)) {
    jsonResponse.forEach((work_order) => {
      //...
    });
  } else {
    throw Error('Server response was not an array');
  }
});
```